# How to clear a session variable once the user logout in laravel 5.2 auth system

Tags: laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2 auth system to manage users but i have to delete a specific session variable after user logged out from the site. but i dont know where to place the session destroy function to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Session::flush();` to delete all variable

And `Session::forget('key');` for particular key.

Use any of these after `Logout` and before you redirect to some page which could look like as below

```
public function getLogout() {
    auth()->logout();

    return redirect()->route('index');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i faced same issue and solved by using `Session::forget('password_hash')`

```
public function doLogout() {
 
 Session::forget('password_hash');
 Auth::logout();
 return Redirect::to(route( 'home').'/');

}
```

Find session values by `dd(Session::all());`