# delete a session value on click of a button

Tags: laravel-4, session-variables

can you help me on how to delete a session value on click of a button. I know how to clear a session key. I have a Session array with array values. I displayed each session array using for-each. I want to delete a specific key when i click a button:

[image]

```
        @if(Session::get('selected_product'))
        @foreach(Session::get('selected_product') as $key => $product )
            <?php print_r(Session::get('selected_product')[$key]); ?>
             <a href="javascript:void()" data-id="" class="deleterow" title="Delete" alt="Delete"><i class="fi-x small"></i></a>
            <fieldset>
                @foreach ($product as $value)
                    <p> {{ $value }}</p>
                @endforeach
            </fieldset>        
        @endforeach
    @endif
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear a session variable once the user logout in laravel 5.2 auth system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36996825/how-to-clear-a-session-variable-once-the-user-logout-in-laravel-5-2-auth-system)

Comment: Hi, I know how to clear a session key, but in my case, i have a Session array with array values. I displayed each session array using for-each. I want to delete a specific key when i click a button

Answer (score 0):

On `(.deleterow)` button click pass the `key`, and by using that `key` you can remove particular value from session array.

```
$sessionVariable = Session::get('selected_product');
unset($sessionVariable[$key]);
Session::push('selected_product', $sessionVariable);
```